# STM32H745: how to use HAL functions across both cores (example UART)?

Tags: stm32, uart, hal

I am using UART5 for serial communication from my custom board to my PC. To enable communicating from both CPUs (CM4 and CM7), I use the following configuration in STM32CubeIDE:

[image]

So the corresponding initialization is done via the auto-generated code `MX_UART5_Init()` on CM4. The handle `UART_HandleTypeDef huart5` is automatically placed in `main()` of CM4. Now if I want to send a string to my PC, I can use this HAL function:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart5, (const uint8_t*) strg, strLen, timeout);
```

So far, so good.

The problem is that I cannot call the same function from CM7 because obviously the handle `huart5` is unknown on that core. Therefore I've tried to share the handle `huart5` via shared memory (SRAM4) to make it known to CM7:

```
#define HUART ((UART_HandleTypeDef*) (0x30040000UL))
HUART = huart5;
```

But then the compiler complains that `UART_HandleTypeDef` is undeclared. Indeed, this typedef is declared in the driver `stm32h7xx_hal_uart.h`. But when I try to include this file in my corresponding code on CM7, the compiler barfs with hundreds of errors.

**In general, what is the proper invocation of HAL functions in case I want to use them on both CPUs for something that's initialized on just one of the cores?**

Am I going about serial communication via the dedicated HAL functions from both cores incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I cannot call the same function from CM7 because obviously the handle huart5 is unknown on that core. Therefore I've tried to share the handle huart5 via shared memory (SRAM4) to make it known to CM7:

That is not true.  Your image shows that the UART5 is enabled for CM7 and CM4.  In addition, CM4 is designated as the core that will do the initialization of UART5.  When the Device Configuration Tool runs it will define huart5 in both cores.

If you look in CM4 and CM7's main.c file you will find:

```
UART_HandleTypeDef huart5;
```

To use it outside of main.c simple add the following extern to whatever c file you want to have access to huart5.

```
extern UART_HandleTypeDef huart5;
```

I generally add the extern defs for huart handles to the main.h file in each core.

```
/* Exported constants --------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN EC */
extern UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
extern UART_HandleTypeDef huart4;
extern UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;
extern osEventFlagsId_t MainTaskMasterEventHandle;
extern osEventFlagsId_t debugTaskMasterEventHandle;
extern osTimerId_t sendRxByteToDpmHandle;
extern TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;


/* USER CODE END EC */
```